# Integration by change of variable $\iint (x+y) \, dx \, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am not really sure how to tackle this one. Any help is appreciated!

By using the change of variable $u=x+y$ , $v=x$ evaluate
$$\iint_{Ta} (x+y) \, dx \, dy$$
where $Ta$ is the region in the $xy$ plane bounded by the $x$ and $y$ axes and the line $x+y = a$.

Update: I have since worked out the Jackobian = -1
so am now onto:
$$\iint_{Ta} (x+y) \, dx \, dy$$
$$=\iint_{Ta} (v+u-v) \, du \, dv$$
since $x=v$ and $y=u-v$, so
$$\iint_{Ta} u \, du \, dv$$
I am still struggling with what to put as the limits though!